# How to make a react component update when a self-updating prop changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that self-updates. Let's say every second it changes its state.

```
export class Obj {

  val = 0;

  start = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
     this.update();
    }, 1000);
  }

  update = () => {
    this.val++;
  }

}
```

I think (please correct me if I'm wrong) that a similar alternative would be an object connected to a stream of data, changing its state every few ms to the last value received.

I now want a react component (using hooks) that displays this:

```
function C(obj) {

  return <div>{obj.val}</div>

}
```

My question is, how can I make the component `C` change when the val of `obj` changes? I could use a callback on every change, but it feels like I'd be polluting my models only for the sake of React. An alternative would be to move the interval outside of `Obj` into the React component but that might not be what I want, and would not cover the case of a stream.

Is there a standard approach in React to update a (functiona, hook based) component when some of its props changes its state?

Comment: What is this syntax? Obj is a class? Also, the component renders by itself on props change

Answer (score 1):

To update React component you need to use any React API, render component's parent (if not memoized), or change its props. Updating the value of an object/class won't notify React.

There are many approaches to make React aware of the object change like the one you described.

A less familiar one is using [`this.forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) it manually forces a render of a component, it widely uses in React wrappers for common libraries.

Here is a usage example with hooks:

```
class Obj {
  val = 0;

  start = sideEffect => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.update();
      sideEffect();
    }, 1000);
  };

  update = () => {
    this.val++;
    console.log(this.val);
  };
}

const obj = new Obj();

const App = () => {
  const [, render] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const renderOnUpdate = () => {
      obj.start(render);
    };
    renderOnUpdate();
  }, []);

  return <>{obj.val}</>;
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-mountain-r2hyt]

Answer (score 0):

The component needs to have a state, which can be updated via the `setState` method. When you have a changing prop, it might make sense to provide a callback method from your react component, which, when called, executes `setState` under the hood.

Comment: The example I've posted is quite contrived and using a callback updating the state with `useState` would be enough. But I've seen that in some more complex cases where the object state changes frequently (EG: a stream) this might create some race conditions. Do you have experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

In this case component `C` won't be re-rendered since its props (`obj`) has never been changed. Objects are compared by reference and since it is the same object reference that was before nothing happens.

You can use component `C` like this to make it re-render: `<C value={obj.val} />`, so on every `obj.val` update it will react correspondingly since its prop now is changing.

Also you could have this logic inside:

```
const obj = new Obj();

function C() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue(value + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval); // don't forget to do cleanup
    }; 
  }, []);

  return <div>{value}</div>
}
```

Comment: This approach certainly works. The problem is that it's not always possible to move the updating logic autoside of an object.